# Thrift error while generating python client file

Tags: python, hbase, thrift, happybase

I'm new to Hbase and I would like to comunicate with it throught a python API which works with Thrift. I've followed this [tutorial](http://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) in order to install it properly on my machine, everything seemed to worked fine then I generated a .thrift file with the following command:

```
wget http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-thrift/src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift\?view\=markup 
-O hbase.thrift
```

Then I tried to generate my client like it's showed [here](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/) but i get the following error message:

```
[ERROR:/home/tests/hbase/hbase.thrift:12] (last token was '<')
syntax error
[FAILURE:/home/tests/hbase/hbase.thrift:12] Parser error during include pass.
```

I tried to lookup on internet what was the cause of this error and found this [paper](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1274), I tried to lookup in thriftl.ll to see if I could correct the error but I found that the correction was already present in the file.

What can I do more in order to make this work ?

Thank you !

EDIT:
I'm using thrift 0.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a fairly recent Thrift version [and more importantly the proper URL](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-thrift/src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift?view=co) I was able to generate Python sources without errors.

Please check if your download is actually a Thrift file or if it is a HTML source. The error message sounds very much like that, since HTML pages typically start with an `<`, and the right Thrift file contains the first `<` at line 110 (within `list<Mutation>`), not around line 12.

PS: Why are you using such an old version? 0.9.1 was released a year ago and 0.9.2 is actually in the process of being released.

PPS: Actually, the referenced ticket [THRIFT-1274](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1274) seems not have much to do with it. But maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed it was an HTML file :( I used this version following instructions of my python API tutorial, they were recomanding Thrift 0.9.0 so I've prefered using this version instead of a newer that could have some bugs with my API.